# Firebase Google SignIn failed - "Audience Mismatch"

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, google-signin

I have implemented **Google sign in via Firebase** and followed proper documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

I am using,

```
- FirebaseUI/Auth (8.5.1):
    - Firebase/Auth (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults
  - FirebaseUI/Google (8.5.1):
    - FirebaseUI/Auth
    - GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)

COCOAPODS: 1.9.3

XCode - 12
```

So, my `Appdelegate.swift` would contain following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`...

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

And presenting SignIn UI when user presses a special button on Login view controller using below code,

```
if let authController = authUI?.authViewController() {
            self.authController = authController
            self.present(authController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

`LoginViewController.swift` would have following code into `viewDidload()`

```
authUI?.delegate = self
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIGoogleAuth()
        ]
        
        authUI?.providers = providers
```

*where `authUI` is declared as property for `LoginViewController` => `let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()`*

**I have only added Google SignIn for now so only one provider added here.**

Now when my SignIn Auth UI is presented, Google SignIn button is shown and I am able to log into my Google account but when `didSignInWith authDataResult` is executed from `FUIAuthDelegate`, I get to know **I am receiving an error post successful Google Account Login**.

```
Error Domain=FUIAuthErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={FUIAuthErrorUserInfoProviderIDKey=google.com, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000a08720 {Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.general Code=-15 "Audience mismatch" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Audience mismatch}}}
```

Is there anything I am missing?

I have already setup URL schema into `info.plist` and not getting any clue on how this kind of error is being generated.

**Further as an update to @frank-van-puffelen,**

I have confirmed proper **info.plist** is added or not.

My `Info.Plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>847792004435-gdisqis038je5q8rr1on4ti7df09nvht.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.847792004435-gdisqis038je5q8rr1on4ti7df09nvht</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>AIzaSyDRrYM2h1wOEdKHZtOM-M904oBwrXnaO3E</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>847792004435</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>com.Speare.StashAlpha</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>stash-demo-11379</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>stash-demo-11379.appspot.com</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>1:847792004435:ios:867e5fb8113b83b48f55a6</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>https://stash-demo-11379.firebaseio.com</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Screenshot of project which is targeted for login,

[image]

We can clearly check here Project ID matches in `info.plist` as well as on Sign In screen.

Now in Firebase console, if we check, project ID matches and below is `info.plist` download button from where I can take latest info.plist.

[image]

Let me know if there is anything we can confirm info.plist does not match with target project.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I have edited my post to include other details you might want to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message usually means that you're trying to sign in to a different project than what the token was minted for. So you might want to check if you have the info.plist for the correct project, and that you're set up you OAuth sign in against that same project.

Comment: Apologies @FrankvanPuffelen for not checking this out prompt as I was on some other priorities. Thanks for your help. I have edited my questions and added info.plist and some screenshots of login process where we can confirm that info.plist is for correct project. Let me know if there are any other pointers here.

Comment: I had created fresh new project on Firebase and added a fresh iOS app on this project and added info.plist into my iOS project which resolved the issue.